# AWS SES smpt failing on port 25 after working for nearly a year

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a java app that uses javax mail to send emails through amazons SES. I send mail over smtp port 25 and haven't made any code changes to my email class in nearly a year. It has worked fine without issue until today. Now it appears to be timing out my application and occasionally sending an email. I'm seeing 100's of lines of the following in the log, not really sure what it means.

2014-11-06 19:20:11,320 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-11-06 19:20:11,320 [DEBUG] Receiving messages for queue https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxx
2014-11-06 19:20:31,391 [DEBUG] Receiving messages for queue https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxx
2014-11-06 19:20:51,461 [DEBUG] Receiving messages for queue https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxx
2014-11-06 19:21:11,531 [DEBUG] Receiving messages for queue https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxx
2014-11-06 19:21:31,608 [DEBUG] Receiving messages for queue https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxx

At one point it appeared as if I was having a connection issue. The only thing I can think of is the fact I'm now using https, however I've been using it for nearly 2 weeks without issue. Does anybody know why all of a sudden his would become an issue?

Comment: When did 2 weeks become nearly a year?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch read the question again and you'll realize the apps been up and running on 80 for nearly a year but recently converted to 443 a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Are you sending more mails than the throttling limit? What is the error that you see?

Comment: Strangly no, I only sent around 500 emails befor this started happening which is completely normal. I emded up switching to port 587 and it seemed to resolve the issue.